# Shorter way to make colliderect in if statement work?

Tags: python, pygame

I have two objects:

```
#Object1
enemigo=pygame.image.load("enemigo.png").convert_alpha()
enemigo=pygame.transform.scale(enemigo, (100, 100))
enemigo_rectangulo=enemigo.get_rect(center=(1000, 100))

#Object2
enemigo2=pygame.image.load("enemigo2.png").convert_alpha()
enemigo2=pygame.transform.scale(enemigo2, (140, 140))
enemigo_rectangulo2=enemigo2.get_rect(center=(1400, 50))
```

And I want to make an `if` statement if they collide with a third object. This code actually works but is too long:

```
if personaje_rectangulo.colliderect(enemigo_rectangulo) or personaje_rectangulo.colliderect(enemigo_rectangulo2):
```

And there's an error when I try to write:

```
if personaje_rectangulo.colliderect(enemigo_rectangulo, enemigo_rectangulo2):
```

So, what is wrong? Is there a shorter way to write it?

Comment: Too long by whose standards? Looks very reasonable to me. And much better than a cute, short line that nobody can understand.

Comment: Have you read [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)? *"Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses."* Ctrl+F for "long" to see other related tips.

Comment: You could make the variable names shorter, i.e. rename `personaje_rectangulo` to `person_rect` or even shorter `pr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you can do is use shorter variable names, such as `personaje` and `enemigo`.

Additionally, break the statement into smaller pieces by using variables:

```
hit_enemy1 = personaje_rectangulo.colliderect(enemigo_rectangulo)
hit_enemy2 = personaje_rectangulo.colliderect(enemigo_rectangulo2)

if hit_enemy1 or hit_enemy2:
    pass
```

Alternatively, if you store all of the enemies in a list, you can use `any()`:

```
if any(personaje_rectangulo.colliderect(enemigo_rectangulo) for enemigo_rectangulo in todos_enemigos):
    pass
```

Now this is also getting long so creating a function to help can shorten the line of code:

```
def collision(person, enemy):
    return person.colliderect(enemy)

if any(collision(person, enemy) in todos_enemigos):
    pass
```

Another solution is to create a `Enemy` class which encapsulates the data and behavior of an enemy. This is a bit more advanced, but definitely a good exercise to learn what classes are and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collidelist()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist):

> Test whether the rectangle collides with any in a sequence of rectangles. The index of the first collision found is returned. If no collisions are found an index of -1 is returned.

```py
if personaje_rectangulo.collidelist([enemigo_rectangulo, enemigo_rectangulo2]) >= 0:
```